# bindIP does not allow range of IP address

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, network-programming

I am using GCP where i create VM at runtime. Now I am want to allow this new VM to talk to my mongodb (mongo 4.0.6)

The ip address or hostname is not known before creation of VM.

One thing I know that IP is going to start with 10.11.*.* or hostname is going to start with client-*

I want restrict access to my mongodb using **net.bindIP**

but net.bindIP **does not allow range**.

could you please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Can you keep your hostname as static?

Comment: Assign a static IP address (VPC Network -> External IP addresses) to your instance.

Comment: Hi @Mani, I can keep have static hostname. But it is not known before i configure **mongodb.conf**

Comment: You could pay for a permanent GCP static address so you would know what it was whenever you set up mongodb, and then associate that address to your VM whenever you create it.